# PHP bind 9 management

Tags: php, bind

Is anyone in knowledge of a PHP class that I could use to manage a named.conf file? Or does anyone have any recommendations for doing this? I imagine this is a pretty common task, but seems like nobody wrote about this

Comment: [Try using answer given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057733/how-to-parse-a-conf-file-in-php) it may the solution you are looking for

Comment: Well, yeah, but bind conf files and httpd.conf have pretty different structures

Comment: There is a function in the PHP Core: array parse_ini_file ( string $filename [, bool $process_sections = false [, int $scanner_mode = INI_SCANNER_NORMAL ]] ) http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php Also the Zend framework provides a class wrapped arround this function: Zend_Config http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html Pear also provides a class with the ability to also write configuration: Config_Lite http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to manage with PHP?

I had to manage one entry to organise some sort of dynamic dns using PHP/WEB + BIND9 conf file. Ended up with having some PLACEHOLDERS, and then reading the value between those placeholders.

e.g.

#### PLACEHOLDER

www CNAME .........
ftp CNAME ......

#### PLACEHOLDER

Comment: i want to add new subdomains programatically and I think your idea might just work.