# Apache config parser for PHP

Tags: php, apache

I am looking for some PHP utility that parses Apache configuration files similar to this Perl's module: http://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::ConfigParser

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PEAR::Config](http://pear.php.net/package/Config/redirected) supports Apache-style config files.
Have a look at the manual http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.configuration.config.avail-container.apache.php

```
$conf = new Config();
$root = $conf->parseConfig("/etc/apache2/httpd.conf", "apache");
print current($root->getItem('directive', 'Listen'))->content;
```

Or something like that..

Comment: It seems that the pear website is down for me. I will take a look at it when it comes back up, thank you!